# What is the differential of $X'X$?

Tags: matrix-calculus, differential

Let $X = (x_{ij})$ be a square matrix with $n\times n$ variables in $\mathbf{R}$. Could you tell me the $\text{d}(X'X)$ when $X$ has a full column rank?

---

## [Update]

Honestly speaking. What I have got is:
$$
\text{d} X'X = (\text{d} X')X  + X'\text{d}X. \tag{1}
$$

But the text book of [matrix differential calculus with applications in statistics and econometrics](http://www.janmagnus.nl/misc/mdc2007-3rdedition) seems give a different result at page 171 excercise 3 as stated below:

> Show that $\text{d} \log |X'X| = 2 \text{ tr}(X'X)^{-1}X'\text{d}X$ at every point where $X$ has full column rank.

As I know:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{d} \log |X'X| &= \text{ d} \text{ tr}(\log|X'X|) \\
& = \text{ tr}(\text{d}\log|X'X|) \\
& = \text{ tr}((X'X)^{-1}\text{d}(X'X)) \\
\end{align}
$$

With result in (1), I cannot obtain $\text{d} \log |X'X| = 2 \text{ tr}(X'X)^{-1}X'\text{d}X$ as stated above. Could you help me to solve this?

Comment: What are you using $X'$ do denote? Transpose?

Comment: @erfink yes. $X'$ is the transpose of matrix $X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some exploration, I intend to answer my question.

Lets assume $X$ has $m\times n$ variables where $m \leq n$.

First we have 
$$
{\rm d} XX' = ({\rm d}X)X' + X({\rm d}X'). \tag{1}
$$

Then

$$
\begin{align}
{\rm d} |XX'| &= {\rm tr} \big( (XX')^\# {\rm d} (XX') \big) \\
& = {\rm tr} \bigg( (XX')^\# \big(({\rm d}X)X' + X({\rm d}X')\big)\bigg)\\
& = {\rm tr} \bigg( (XX')^\# ({\rm d}X)X' + (XX')^\#X{\rm d}X'\bigg)\\
& = {\rm tr} \bigg( X'(XX')^\# ({\rm d}X)\bigg) + {\rm tr}\bigg( (XX')^\#X{\rm d}X'\bigg)\\
& = {\rm tr} \bigg( X'(XX')^\# ({\rm d}X)\bigg) + {\rm tr}\bigg(X' (XX')^\#{\rm d}X \bigg)\\
& = 2 {\rm tr} \bigg( X'(XX')^\# ({\rm d}X)\bigg)
\end{align}
$$

Futher

$$
\begin{align}
{\rm d} \log |XX'| &= \frac{1}{|XX'|} {\rm d} |XX'| \\
& = \frac{2}{|XX'|} {\rm tr} \bigg( X'(XX')^\# {\rm d}X\bigg) \\
& = 2\ {\rm tr} \bigg( X'\frac{(XX')^\#}{|XX'|} {\rm d}X\bigg) \\
& = 2\ {\rm tr} \bigg( X'(XX')^{-1} {\rm d}X\bigg) \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The general rule for differentials is very simple
$$\eqalign{
 d(A\star B) &= dA\star B + A\star dB  \cr
}$$
where $\star$ can be the Hadamard, Kronecker, Dyadic, Frobenius, or normal matrix product, and the matrices $(A,B)$ are such that their dimensions are compatible with the specified product.

In your particular case, the rule tells us that 
$$\eqalign{
 d\,(X^TX) &= dX^TX + X^TdX  \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: The question was updated. Could you help me in the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

It is often useful to take the derivative of a scalar-valued function or a vector-valued function with respect to a vector. I have not come across the situation where I need to take the derivative of a matrix. Hopefully, this explanation is helpful to you.

The first derivative of a scalar-valued function $f(\mathbf{x})$ with respect to a vector is called the gradient of $f(\mathbf{x})$ where $\mathbf{x} = [x_1 \;x_2]^T$. We can write this as

$$\nabla f (\mathbf{x}) = \frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}} f (\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
         \frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x_1} \\
         \frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x_2}
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}} (x_1^2 + x_2^2) = 2 
         \begin{bmatrix}
         x_1 \\
         x_2
        \end{bmatrix} = 2 \mathbf{x}$$

If we are taking the first derivative of a vector-valued function with respect to a vector, it is called the Jacobian. It is given by,

$$J (\mathbf{x}) = \frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}} f (\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
         \frac{\partial  f_1}{\partial  x_1} \frac{\partial  f_1}{\partial  x_2}\\
         \frac{\partial  f_2}{\partial  x_1} \frac{\partial  f_2}{\partial  x_2}
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Edit: I just realized you said $\mathbf{x}$ is a matrix. However, I edited my answer for clarification.

Comment: Could you solve my case in which $X$ is a matrix of variables